# Populate in node.js with two separately exported modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've two schemas in two different files in my express app.

Say  **A.js** has SchemaA connected to  collectionA

```
var SchemaA=new Schema({
  name: String,
  ...
}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('collectionA', SchemaA);
```

and **B.js** has SchemaB connected to collectionB but also has a DBref to the SchemaA

```
var ModelA=require('./A.js');
var SchemaB = new Schema({
  an_id:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ModelA' }],
  name:String
)};

module.exports =mongoose.model('collectionB', SchemaB);
```

How do I populate the SchemaB. It's giving me Schema hasn't registered error. If i redelcare the schema again, then it says model has been populated before itself.

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around. I figured out that we can call the already compiled schemas by

```
var ModelA = mongoose.model('collectionA');
```

And in the DBref  , `ref:'ModelA'` will do the magic. However,`var ModelA=require('./A.js');` is needed to be called before  mongoose.model is called , so that the model is compiled in that file itself.